# How to create multiplied identity t-sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

how to set up identity properties in t-sql in order to increment an id in the way: previous id mulitply by 2. E.g.:  `2 (=>1x2), 4 (2x2),8 (4x2), 16 (8x2)` and so on.. any ideas?

Comment: May I ask why you would like to do this?

Comment: I need to have both: unique values of id and possibility of sum it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot create a multiplied identity.

I'm assuming, what you are looking for is a column with power of 2.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472450/is-there-a-way-to-generate-identity-or-sequence-that-increments-in-power-of-2) for solution.

Comment: Yes. Did you paste some link?